# Wired Connection not working in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, network-connection

Wired connection was not identified by Ubuntu.

Here's my result if I run `ifconfig -a` on terminal

```
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
    inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
    inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
    loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
    RX packets 308  bytes 22700 (22.7 KB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 308  bytes 22700 (22.7 KB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

 wlp1s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 10.42.0.249  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.42.0.255
    inet6 fe80::a78:589e:2107:b3c4  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether dc:53:60:e2:ce:99  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 13416  bytes 9588247 (9.5 MB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 9109  bytes 1698278 (1.6 MB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Help me to get out of this

Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 0):

The following helped me (I'm not quite sure why, but it did! :D)

Check ethernet state with

```sh
$ nmcli device
```

Check if there are errors or warnings from NetworkManager

```sh
$ systemctl status NetworkManager.service
```

Go root:

```sh
$ sudo -s
```

Delete all files in the directory `/var/lib/NetworkManager/` except `secret_key`

```sh
$ cd /var/lib/NetworkManager/
$ rm -v !("secret_key")
```

Now reboot system and check ethernet state with `nmcli device`

If that does not help, you can create an empty file with this command and restart the computer again.
`sudo touch /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf`

> Source: https://forum.ubuntuusers.de/topic/kein-netzzugriff/